# How much Uranium would a country like Iran need to produce for supplying its Technetium needs?

Tags: estimation, radioactivity, nuclear-engineering, medical-physics

<sub>This is not a question about politics, although the motivation is a political situation.</sub>

Iran, which enriches Uranium to a level of $60\%$ $\rm{^{235}U}$, is claiming it has civilian uses for this enriched material. I assume there could be more than one such use, but this question focuses on the use of HEU for producing [$\rm{^{99m}Te}$, meta-stable Technetium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technetium-99m), used in medical imaging.

Iran had $\sim86.5$ Million inhabitants as of $2022$. I don't know how many SPECT scanners they have, so just assume whatever level of coverage of the population by scanners that you can quantify, even if it's not Iran's but the US' or an EU country's, and we can consider normalization ex-post-facto (or not normalize and have an overly-generous estimate). Assume also whichever distribution you like of technology age of deployed scanners w.r.t. the necessary dose per scan, assume any reasonable distribution of the kind of scans performed etc.

Under all of these assumptions - which I realize might not be easy to make - how much $60\%$ HEU would Iran need to produce (in $\mathrm{kg} / \text{day}$ or $\mathrm{kg} / \text{year}$) to satisfy its Technetium needs?

Comment: From Wikipedia: “Global shortages of technetium-99m emerged in the late 2000s because two aging nuclear reactors (NRU and HFR) that provided about two-thirds of the world's supply of molybdenum-99, which itself has a half-life of only 66 hours, were shut down repeatedly for extended maintenance periods.“ So, one reactor would supply a significant fraction of the world’s demand.

Comment: @JonCuster: 1. Ok, but - how large of a reactor? That's why I asked about Kilograms of enriched material, since that's a statistic we have quantified about Iran from the IAEA.

Comment: NRU was a 135MW reactor. HFR is a 60MW reactor, now using low-enriched fuel. HFR is slated to be replaced by a 80MW reactor. NRU and HFR were fairly small systems, designed with experiments (which lead to isotope production). As of the late 1990s the HRF used about 40kg/yr of HEU, total amount of Uranium in the LEU fuels is going to be about that order of magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

Speculative upper-bound answer based on @JonCuster's comment: No more than $6.5 ~\frac{\mathrm{kg}}{\text{year}}$.

Suppose for exaggeration that Iran can use $5\%$ of all Technetium  used in the world (this circumvents the need to estimate things about dose policies, distribution of imaging scans etc.)

Suppose also that with HEU you need no more fuel than with LEU (this is a completely baseless assumption on my part, Physicists please correct me.)

Suppose that fuel use grows more-or-less linearly with reactor energy output.

@JonCuster reports that the two reactors which have so far provided the global Technetium needs were $135 ~\mathrm{MW}$ and $60 ~\mathrm{MW}$ respectively, and the smaller one used $40 ~\frac{\mathrm{kg}}{\text{year}}$ of Uranium.

By our assumptions, the two reactors together used $\left( 1 + \frac{135}{60} \right) \cdot 40 ~\frac{\mathrm{kg}}{\text{year}} = 3.25 \cdot 40 ~\frac{\mathrm{kg}}{\text{year}} = 130 ~\frac{\mathrm{kg}}{\text{year}}$ of Uranium. $5\%$ of this is $6.5 ~\frac{\mathrm{kg}}{\text{year}}$. So, under our assumptions, Iran should not need more than $6.5 ~\mathrm{kg}$ of $60\%$-enriched Uranium each year for Technetium production.